# When to resort to Tschebysheff's inequality?

Tags: confidence-interval, estimation

Suppose I have an unbiased estimator $\hat{\beta}$ with mean 5 and standard deviation 1, and suppose that $\hat{\beta}=5.5$.  I want to know at least how great is the confidence associated with the interval $\beta\in[3,8]$.

Without knowing anything about the distributions of $\beta$ or $(\hat{\beta}-\beta)/\sigma_{\hat{\beta}}$, am I forced to resort to Tschebysheff's inequality here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be completely precise if all you're willing to assume about a distribution is the mean and variance then no, you cannot find a better bound than Chebyshev's.  To see this we can define a random variable $X$ taking values in the set $\{-1, 0, 1 \}$ with respective probabilities $\{p, 1 - 2p, p \}$ where $0 < 2p < 1$.  For this distribution we have $\text{E}(X) = 0$ and $\text{Var}(X) = \text{E}(X^2) = 2p$ and Chebyshev's inequality states that

$$
P(|X| \geq 1) \leq 2p .
$$

But notice that we actually have equality here, which means we could not have obtained a tighter upper bound.  The implication is that in general Chebyshev's inequality cannot be improved upon without additional constraints.

Also, since the variance is estimated from the data rather than being known this approach isn't strictly valid as whuber points out.

Comment: Chebyshev's inequality *does not apply* when the mean and variance are estimated!  In particular, its use can lead to arbitrarily bad confidence intervals (their actual confidence levels can approach zero).  Their levels can also approach $1$--it's not a matter of confidence always being smaller.  The size of the error depends on the true underlying distribution.

Comment: Nice comment whuber. Now, tell that to the EPA and the designers of ProUCL.

Comment: Great comment whuber. Does that imply Chebyshev's inequality has no real world application, since the "true" underlying distribution, mean, and variance is never "truly" known?